# How to use same storyboard with proper view in both iPhone and iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to create a app for both iPhone and iPad. Is there any easy way for that so i don't need to create two different storyboard for iPhone and iPad? How can i change whole app font size and view height and width automatically  when app run in iPad  and iPhone.

Comment: use size class for storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for Size Classes. They are the more recommended way to do that :) 
Take a look at this article https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/designing-for-size-classes-in-ios/

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Default Main storyboard is used by iPhone and iPad devices. To differentiate the app design a developer has a tools like Size Classes, Auto-Layout, UITraitCollection and [more](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/)

**Extra informations:**

A default app template in Xcode builds for iPhone and iPad device.

Build Settings

```
TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1,2 //iPhone = 1, iPad = 2
```

Default iPhone/iPad Storyboard is defined in Info.plist with key `UIMainStoryboardFile` . There is another key `UIMainStoryboardFile~iPad` which sets a storyboard file for an iPad.